# input into javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, input

I can't figure out how to have a javascript function which accepts a parameter correctly.

I can get the function working perfectly if I don't use a input parameter because I can do this:

```
var x = MyFunction;
```

But the moment I have to do this

```
 var x = MyFunction(e);
```

Then it breaks.

I tried to work around this by setting the input parameter afterwards, but I can't get anything to work. How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TxMmG/

```
var MyFunction = function() {

    var otherResult = function() {
        alert("Hi");
    },

        input, objToAlert = function() {
            return input;
        };

    return {
        objToAlert: objToAlert,
        input: input,
        otherResult: otherResult
    }

}();


var e1 = "test";


//var y = MyFunction(e); //this does not work if i add a parameter to function - moment i put parenthesis i get problems
var x = MyFunction;
x.input = e1; //also cant set the input here
x.objToAlert();
x.otherResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a `()` after the function definition, so the function is called and `MyFunction` is actually the object returned by the function, not the function itself.

Do like this:

```
var MyFunction = function() {
    // ...
};  // No () here
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function returns an object. Therefore you're assigning an object to a var y. You can not treat object as a function.